# mysql inner join returns duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, join

Hello Developers I have two tables, combining via mysql join, getting multiple rows instead of single row, please solve this problem,

```
tbltestdefault
-----------------------------------------------
ID   Test_ID           Description
-----------------------------------------------
1    117                  Blood Group   
2    117                  Rh Factor
3     4                   HB
4     4                     RBC
5     4                     ESR

tblreportdetail
-----------------------------------------------
ID   Test_Default_ID           Result_Value
-----------------------------------------------
1     117                               A
2     117                              Positive
3      4                              12
4      4                                15
5      4                                25
```

my query is

```
SELECT a.Description,
b.Result_Value
from tbltestdefault a
inner join tblreportdetail b on a.Test_ID  = b.Test_Default_ID
```

this query is returning multiple rows

result of above query

```
tblreportdetail
Description    Result_Value
HB          12
HB          15    
HB          25
HB          12
RBC         15
RBC         25
RBC         12
RBC         15
ESR         
ESR
ESR
ESR
Blood Group   
Blood Group   
Blood Group   
Blood Group   
Rh Factor
Rh Factor
Rh Factor
Rh Factor
```

Comment: Did you have a question you wanted to ask? Or were you just giving a status report?

Comment: the question is why i am getting duplicate rows?

Answer (score 2):

They're not dupes. You're getting exactly what you asked for. If you add the two table IDs to your query, you'll see they're not dupes, e.g.

```
Description    Result_Value   a.id   b.id
HB             12             3      3
HB             15             3      4
HB             25             3      5
HB             12             4      3
HB             15             4      4
HB             25             4      5
etc...
```

Comment: no, I just have Test_ID and Test_Default_ID no unique ID

Answer (score 2):

**Q: the question is why i am getting duplicate rows?**

**A:** The rows with identical content are being produced in the resultset returne by the query, because of the specified JOIN predicate, and because there are multiple rows in each table that have the same `Test_ID`/`Test_Default_ID` values.

The expected result from the query, given the data shown, would be total of 13 rows. That's 2*2 + 3*3.

Each of the two `Test_ID`=117 rows matches two `Test_Default_ID`=117 rows, for a total of 4 rows returned.

Each of the three `Test_ID`=4 rows matches three `Test_Default_ID`=4 rows, for a total of 9 rows returned.

Because the query doesn't include any unique identifiers of the rows in the resultset, the contents of some of the rows returned are identical.

That's why you are observing "duplicate rows" returned by the query.

Comment: can you help me how i can add a unique identifier between these two tables?